# Scrapy crawl soccer statistics with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, selenium, dynamic, request, scrapy

I will scrape some Data from squawka.com with scrapy. The code is shown bewlow. First I go to the result page. Here I search Detailed Match Stats links from the german Bundesliga and also it crawls all pagination links and send a request. All works fine but only in the "for Liga in Ligas loop" I make a request that doesn't work fine, because of the dynamic stuff behind. If the link is loaded I can scrape the Team names, scores, Date, Arena name, but I can't scrape e.g. the Shots for the home team (item['ShotsA'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='mc-stat-shot']/div/div[@class='team2-data']/text()").extract() is empty when I'm scraping) because of the dynamic behaviour. I try some things with selenium with no success. Can someone help me with the request command or with selenium?

```
import scrapy
from soccer.items import SoccerItem
from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

class SquawkaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "soccer"
     allowed_domains = ["squawka.com"]
     start_urls = ["http://www.squawka.com/match-results"]

def __init__(self):
    #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/fabian/chromedriver')
    #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):

    #self.driver.get("response.url")
    #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='league-filter-list']/option[contains(text(), 'Top 5 European Leagues')]").click()
    Matches = response.xpath("//tr[@class='match-today']")
    counter = response.xpath("//div/center/div[@id='sq-pagination']/span/span[@class='page-numbers current']/text()").extract()[0]

    if counter == "1":
        yield scrapy.Request(url="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?ctl=22_s2014", cookies={'firsttime_new': '1', 'sqhome_competition': '126', 'sqhome_competitionidinfeed': '22', 'sqhome_competitionteam': '0', 'sqhome_seasonid': '2014', 'timeZone': '2.0'}, callback=self.parse)

    for Match in Matches:
        Ligas = Match.xpath("td[@class='match-league']/a/text()").extract()
        for Liga in Ligas:
            if Liga == "Bundesliga":
                Matchlinks = Match.xpath("td[@class='match-centre']/a/@href").extract()
                yield scrapy.Request(Matchlinks[0], callback=self.parse_match_link)


    if counter == "1":
        page = response.xpath("//div/center/div[@id='sq-pagination']/span/a[@class='pageing_text_arrow'][1]/@href")
    if counter != "1":
        page = response.xpath("//div/center/div[@id='sq-pagination']/span/a[@class='pageing_text_arrow'][3]/@href")

    if page:
        next = page.extract()
        yield scrapy.Request(next[0], cookies={'firsttime_new': '1', 'sqhome_competition': '126', 'sqhome_competitionidinfeed': '22', 'sqhome_competitionteam': '0', 'sqhome_seasonid': '2014', 'timeZone': '2.0'}, callback=self.parse)

def parse_match_link(self, response):

    item = SoccerItem()

    item['TeamH'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='team1']/ul[@class='team-lineup']/li[@id='team1-select']/text()").extract()
    item['GoalH'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='sq-mc-top-header']/div[@id='mc-header-team-1']/div[@class='team-score'][1]/span/text()").extract()
    item['ShotsH'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='mc-stat-shot']/div/div[@class='team1-data']/text()").extract()

    item['TeamA'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='team2']/ul[@class='team-lineup']/li[@id='team2-select']/text()").extract()
    item['GoalA'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='sq-mc-top-header']/div[@id='mc-header-team-2']/div[@class='team-score'][1]/span/text()").extract()
    item['ShotsA'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='mc-stat-shot']/div/div[@class='team2-data']/text()").extract()

    item['Date'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='sq-mc-top-header']/div[@id='mc-header-date']/text()").extract()
    item['Stadium'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='sq-mc-top-header']/div[@id='mc-header-stadium']/text()").extract()
    yield item

    #self.driver.get(response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the AJAX requests that the site is doing in that particular page and recreate them in your Scrapy code. If you use a modern browser, you will have developer tools available that allow you to do this. For example in Firefox press F12 and look at the Network tab.

There's a chance the site is not using AJAX to populate those dynamic sections (but that's the case in most sites) so you will need to look deeper in the page to find out what it's doing. It could be using plain Javascript to fetch the data from a hidden section within the page, in which case the information is there but you just need to extract it from a different element. The site could also be using more complex communication means as Websockets, if this is the case you probably won't be able to get the data with Scrapy.

Comment: @ Javier Ayres! Thanks for your answer. I had lokok In the devoloper tool but there are many Request and don't find some usefull things. That ist one link http://b-liga.squawka.com/1fc-kln-vs-vfl-wolfsburg/23-05-2015/german-bundesliga/matches and from there i want to scrape the shots and other things. Where can i find more details in the devolpoer tool of chrome or firefox with firebug which request important is?

Comment: Filter by the type column. You don't want requests that returned CSS, Javascript, images, etc. You probably want requests that returned JSON, HTML or XML. From there you will have to look each response to see if that's the content you are looking for.